# Binary Tree MIN and MAX Depth

Tags: binary-tree, binary-search-tree, depth

I am having trouble with these questions:

**A binary tree with N nodes is at least how deep?
How deep is it at most?**

Would the maximum depth just be N?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two extremes that you need to consider.

1. Every node has just a left(or right) child, but not right child. In which case your binary search tree is merely a linkedlist in practice.
2. Every level in your tree is full, maybe except the last level. This type of trees are called **complete**.
3. Third type of tree that I know may not be relevant to your question. But it is called **full** tree and every node is either a leaf or has n number of childs for an n-ary tree.

So to answer your question. Max depth is N. And at least it has log(N) levels, when it is a complete tree.